# Options for a Client Only C# application

Tags: client, thin-clients, c#

If I want to create a client only, C# desktop application, what are my options for working with Bitcoin?

- I could try to port BitcoinJ, which seems like a lot of overhead in terms of initial effort and keeping the project up to date.
- I could try to create a local Bitcoin process which runs a tiny BitcoinJ-based server, and talk to it from C#.

Neither of these seem appealing.

- I could use the Blockchain API.
- I could set up my own server and run the wallets on the server.

Neither of these seem appealing either.

Anyone know of an easier way to run a Bitcoin client without a full blockchain using C#? I would ideally like users to retain control over their wallets, with the client code finding incoming payments and facilitating the sending of coins.

Comment: Why is it important that it be written in C#?

Comment: For LoB desktop apps, C#/WPF is the weapon of choice. You would need a reason to deviate from that. Java sucks for desktop apps, C++ is hopelessly unproductive for desktop apps. HTML5+JS _might_ be an option, but that would be a bit limiting.

Comment: Well, having a bunch of existing code in another language would seem like a pretty good reason to me.  But what do I know?

Comment: Possibly, but it would be a little bit like the tail wagging the dog.

Comment: @Avram as the author of BitcoinLib (https://github.com/GeorgeKimionis/BitcoinLib) I was contacted by another C# developer who wants to do exactly the same thing as you, you will find my e-mail in my GitHub profile page so please drop me a line there, I can bring you guys in touch and maybe you could team up and build this thing together.

Comment: BitCoinSharp https://code.google.com/p/bitcoinsharp/

Answer (score 2):

Have you guys see this recent GitHub? I too have been poking around looking for a standalone library.

https://github.com/TangibleCryptography/BitSharper

I have it downloaded, just trying to fix dependencies so I can compile.
Looks promising.

Answer (score 2):

NBitcoin supports connection to the bitcoin network.

NBitcoin Github : https://github.com/NicolasDorier/NBitcoin

NBitcoin Nuget : https://www.nuget.org/packages/NBitcoin/

Intro : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/768412/NBitcoin-The-most-complete-Bitcoin-port-Part-Crypt

Stealth Payment, and BIP38 : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/775226/NBitcoin-Cryptography-Part

How to build transaction : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/835098/NBitcoin-Build-Them-All

Using the NBitcoin Indexer : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/819567/NBitcoin-Indexer-A-scalable-and-fault-tolerant-blo

How to Scan the blockchain : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/784519/NBitcoin-How-to-scan-the-Blockchain (You can ignore the ScanState part)